# How do I create an AWS CloudWatch Log group with a KMS key attached to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-kms

I have this log group that requires a cmk from aws kms. The CMK has this policy attached to it (terraform inline policy):

```
module "component_cmk_log" {
  source      = "cmk-logroup-source"
  name        = "${var.environment}_loggroup_cmk"
  environment = terraform.workspace
  key_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cmk-log-group.json
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cmk-log-group" {
  statement {
    sid    = "Enable IAM User Permissions"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${account_id}:root"]
    }

    actions = [
      "kms:*"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["logs.${var.region}.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    actions = [
      "kms:Encrypt*",
      "kms:Decrypt*",
      "kms:ReEncrypt*",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:Describe*"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
    condition {
      test = "ArnLike"
      values = [
        "arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${account_id}:*"
      ]
      variable = "kms:EncryptionContext:arn:aws:logs"
    }
  }

}
```

This is the log group that requires it
When i run terraform apply to this, i get the issue:

```
Creating CloudWatch Log Group failed: AccessDeniedException: The specified KMS key does not exist or is not allowed to be used with LogGroup 'arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:123456789:log-group:/test/dev/applications/loggroup/files.out'
```

What am i missing here? I tried following this documentation but cannot solve: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/encrypt-log-data-kms.html

Comment: The variable is wrong, should be `kms:EncryptionContext:aws:logs:arn` according to the docs.